# Где взять stdafx.h в Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

Установил Visual Studio, скачать всё нужное начал работу и увидел что "stdafx" отсутствует.
Где его можно найти в общем доступе для скачивания и куда его потом скидывать?

Comment: Вот это прочтите https://habr.com/ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/227521/

Comment: gbg,спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

**stdafx.h** - это стандартное название [предварительно скомпилированного заголовочного файла](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files) в Visual Studio 2017 и более ранних версиях. Начиная с VS2019, вместо этого используется **pch.h**. Его не нужно ниоткуда скачивать, в него вписываются часто включаемые в коде заголовочные файлы для ускорения компиляции. Сам файл должен создаваться автоматически при создании проекта; но если его нет, можно добавить его вручную. Содержимое должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
//другие директивы include...
```

Совместно с ним в проекте должен находится **pch.cpp**, состоящий из единственной строки:

```
#include "pch.h"
```

Для использования предварительно скомпилированных заголовков их необходимо включить параметром /Y или через страницу свойств проекта **Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Precompiled Headers**. После этого в каждом cpp-файле в самом начале (до любых директив препроцессора или строк кода) нужно добавить `#include "pch.h"`.